# How does (orientation: landscape) really work in CSS Media Queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Acccording to the preffferd css syntax i am applying the Media Query and it doesnt change anything. This is not giving me any changed output. Help.!

```
  /* Landscape */
  @media only screen 
   and (min-device-width: 320px) 
   and (max-device-width: 480px)
   and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
   and (orientation: landscape) {
     .someClass{
         display: none;
         }
   }
```

Comment: it won't work, because `display:none` property doesn't know **What to hide?** Add the required `class` or tag like `html`, `body` or other.

Comment: I am extremely sorry about not writing any class, which i have corrected . My point here is that whenever i mention the orientation to landscape without defining pixel coordinates it never worked for me. Bassicaly i could not understand what is the right way to apply orientaion. I keep doing the same job by mentioning min-width and max-width for the orientation.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't giving you an output since the usage is wrong. You want to use the property with an HTML selector.

Right syntax:

```css
/* Landscape */
  @media only screen 
   and (min-device-width: 320px) 
   and (max-device-width: 480px)
   and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
   and (orientation: landscape) {
     body {
      display: none;
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   @media only screen 
   and (min-device-width: 320px) 
   and (max-device-width: 480px)
   and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
   and (orientation: landscape) {
     *{ display: none; }
   }
```

Try this, you didn't select anything to hide